Getting ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'\n "_id"'} in Langchain
main.py

llm_openai = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPEN_AI_KEY, model='gpt-3.5-turbo-0125')
table_schema = ConfigData.TABLE_SCHEMA
schema_description = ConfigData.SCHEMA_DESCRIPTION
json_ex_1 = ConfigData.FEW_SHOT_EXAMPLE_1
json_ex_string = json.dumps(json_ex_1)
prompt_template_for_creating_query = """
    You are an expert in crafting NoSQL queries for MongoDB with 10 years of experience, particularly in MongoDB. 
    I will provide you with the table_schema and schema_description in a specified format. 
    Your task is to read the user_question, which will adhere to certain guidelines or formats, and create a NOSQL MongoDb pipeline accordingly.

    Table schema:""" +  table_schema + """
    Schema Description: """ + schema_description + """

    Here are some example:
    Input: Find movies by Quentin Tarantino and include a count of how many actors are in each movie
    Output: {json_ex_string_1} 

    Note: You have to just return the query nothing else. Don't return any additional text with the query.
    Input: {user_question}
    """
query_creation_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template_for_creating_query,
    input_variables=["user_question", "json_ex_string_1"],
)
llmchain = LLMChain(llm=llm_openai, prompt=query_creation_prompt, verbose=True)
def get_query(user_question):
    response = llmchain.invoke({
        "user_question": user_question,
        "json_ex_string_1": json_ex_string
    })

    response_text = response['text'].replace("Output: ", "")
    pattern = r'db\.collectionName\.aggregate\(\s*\['

    output_string = re.sub(pattern, '', response_text)

    return json.loads(output_string)
client = pymongo.MongoClient(ConfigData.MONGO_DB_URI)
db = client[ConfigData.DB_NAME]
collection_name = db[ConfigData.COLLECTION_NAME]
query_1 = get_query(user_question="when InnovateTech Solutions founded?")

getting error :
  ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'\n        "_id"'}

am trying to generate MongoDB aggregation queries using LangChain with OpenAI's GPT-3.5. However, I am encountering a ValueError stating that some input keys are missing.
Here is my setup:

I have a PromptTemplate that should generate MongoDB queries based on a given schema and user question.

I invoke the chain using the invoke method.



You should provide the complete traceback (formatted as code), so others can see exactly what lines of code returned the error in your code and the packages.

Based on my experience, this error typically occurs when you include placeholders enclosed in curly braces '{}' in your chain invocation without providing the corresponding values.
In your specific case, you are passing 'user_question' and 'json_ex_string_1' as arguments. However, I also notice that you are including two additional variables in your prompt: 'table_schema' and 'schema_description'. It is likely that the error originates from one of these two variables.
To resolve this issue, please verify the values of 'table_schema' and 'schema_description'. If they are not intended to be dynamic values (i.e., you do not plan to pass specific values for them), you should escape the curly braces by adding an additional curly brace. For example, '{abcd}' should be rewritten as '{{abcd}}'.
By doing this, you ensure that the curly braces are interpreted as literal text rather than placeholders for dynamic values.
